# Why does copies of the same API call returned undefined for one function and works for the other

Tags: javascript, next.js

While trying to use TMDB API in my project I ran into an issue that I am unable to figure out. I use copies of the same code as shown below in two different files and functions - one works, and the other one returned undefined for some reason. Can you please point out what I am not doing right, I need fresh new eyes on this. Thank you

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';


export const getServerSideProps = async () => {

    const movieApi = process.env.TMDB_API_KEY;
  
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=${movieApi}&page=1`);
    const movie_data = await res.json();
   
    return {
      props: {
        movies : movie_data
      },
    }
  }


const Form = ({movies}) => {
    console.log(movies);  //returns "Undefined"

    const [search, Setsearch] = useState("");

    //Handle input value
    const getLocation = async (e) => {
        // console.log(e.target.value)

        


        e.preventDefault();
      }

    //Handle Submit
    const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        // console.log("clicked")


        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {

  const movieApi = process.env.TMDB_API_KEY;

  const res = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=${movieApi}&page=1`);
  const movie_data = await res.json();
 
  return {
    props: {
      movies : movie_data
    },
  }
}


export default function Home({movies}) {
  console.log(movies); //works perdectly
  const [session, loading] = useSession();

  const tmdbMpviesResults = movies.results
```

Comment: Is <Form /> a route or a component you use at several places?

Comment: @Gh05d - No, I only used it on one page, the homepage

Comment: You can't use `getServerSideProps ` inside components, only in pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, `<Form />` is not a page. [Exactly that](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-allowed-in-a-page-2) is your problem:

> getServerSideProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.